# Where in the Talmud is there a discussion of which books to canonize and who redacted the books of Navi?

Tags: apocrypha

I believe those two discussions were in the same daf. anyone can help?

Comment: Bava Basra 14b-15a is a good place to start

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting this question?

Comment: @רבות do you think this is a good post? How many problems with it can you fit into one comment?

Comment: Not sure what is happening lately here at Mi Yodeya but this hyper-criticism is fatiguing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list as described in Bava Basra. The link is to the Daf Yomi outline of the relevant parts.

[Baba Basra 14b](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/bbasra/points/bb-ps-014.htm) Art Scroll version 14 b 3-4

> WHO WROTE THE SEFORIM
>
> (a)Question: Who wrote Torah, the Nevi'im and Kesuvim?
>
> (b)Answer: Moshe wrote the Torah, including the Parshah of Bilam, and
>   Sefer Iyov;
>
> (c)Yehoshua wrote Sefer Yehoshua and the last eight verses of the
>   Torah;
>
> (d)Shmuel wrote Sefer Shmuel, Shoftim and Rus;
>
> (e)David and ten other Chachamim composed Tehilim - Adam, Malki Tzedek
>   (Shem), Avraham, Moshe, Heiman, Yedusun, Asaf, and Korach's three
>   sons.

[Bava Basra 15a](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/bbasra/points/bb-ps-015.htm)

> WHO WROTE THE SEFORIM (cont.)
>
> (a)Yirmeyahu wrote Sefer Yirmeyahu, Melachim and Eichah;
>
> (b)Chizkiyahu and his contemporaries wrote Yeshayah, Mishlei, Shir
>   ha'Shirim and Koheles;
>
> (c)The men of the Great Assembly wrote Yechezkeil, the 12, Daniel and
>   Megilas Esther;
>
> (d)Ezra wrote Sefer Ezra, and the lineage at the beginning of Divrei
>   ha'Yamim until himself (Rashi; Tosfos - until the verse "v'Lo Achim
>   Benei Yehoshafat");
>
> 1.This supports Rav, who said that Ezra did not leave Bavel until he established his own lineage.
>
> 2.Question: Who finished Divrei ha'Yamim?
>
> 3.Answer: Nechemyah did.
>
> (e)(Beraisa): Yehoshua wrote Sefer Yehoshua and the last eight verses
>   of the Torah.
>
> (f)Tana'im argue about whether Moshe or Yehoshua wrote the last eight
>   verses.
>
> 1.(Beraisa - R. Yehudah or R. Nechemyah): Moshe could not have written "va'Yamas Sham Moshe"!
>
> i.Rather, Moshe wrote until here. Yehoshua wrote the rest.
>
> 2.Objection (R. Shimon): Had Moshe omitted even one letter of the Torah, it would not say "Lako'ach Es Sefer ha'Torah ha'Zeh"!
>
> i.Rather, until here, Hash-m dictated the Torah and Moshe wrote;
>
> ii.For these last eight verses, Hash-m dictated and Moshe wrote b'Dema
>   (with tears; Sefas Emes - he wrote the letters without spaces between
>   words).
>
> 3.Similarly, Yirmeyahu dictated his prophecy to Baruch (who wrote it; Rashi - similarly, Baruch did not repeat the verses due to remorse) -
>   "mi'Piv Yikra Elai... va'Ani Kosev."